# Virtual directory deleted when publishing asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

A short question.
I have a website running at :80.
I create a virtual directory "itemimages" under the site that reference E:\itemimages.

When i publish the ASP.net to the website at :80 with "Delete all existing files prior to publish" the virtual directory "itemimages" is also deleted.

Any way to stop this from happening? 
Or better: Any way to define the virtual directory inside the asp.net application so i will be created in any "fresh" publish?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try publishing the website to the directory, as opposed to the website? I.e. publish to c:\Websites\WebsiteRoot (or whatever the path is), as opposed to http://www.sitename.com/

Or you could try using the "Replace files" instead of deleting all preexisting files ?

Comment: Wow, why did I not think about publishing to the folder only :) I do it all the time before transferring to customers etc... Thanks!